# How can I get all the responses by a particular user to posts on a particular topic

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a user, a micropost and a response model.

The user has many microposts and has many responses.

Microposts have tags using the acts as taggable gem.

I need to find the number of responses a user has, to microposts that are tagged with a specific tag. To be clear, for example, how many responses has user 1 given to microposts on "exercise"

There is some basic ruby syntax and relationship logic I am missing. This is what I haev in my user model.

```
  def user_responses_on_topic tag
      microposts = self.microposts.tagged_with(tag, :on => :tags)
      responses_count = 0
      microposts.each do |micropost|
          count = micropost.responses.where("user_id = :user_id", user_id: self.id).size
          responses_count  = responses_count + count
     end
   end
```

Its giving me a value but I know its wrong because when I add responses on a particular topic the users value doesn't increase.

I am sure there is a simple "ruby" way to get at this using

```
   responses = user.microposts.responses
```

But I need to know how to get the tagged logic on microposts into this code

I have tightened it up a bit but still not luck. The individual components of this code work but I can't get the whole thing to work together

```
 def user_responses_on_topic(interest)
    microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(interest, :on => :tags, :any => true)
    responses ||= 0
    microposts.each do |micropost|
    responses += micropost.responses.where("user_id = :user_id", user_id: self.id).size
   end
 end
```

EDIT:

This works

```
def user_responses_on_topic(interest)
   microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(interest, :on => :tags, :any => true)
   count = 0
     microposts.each do |micropost|
     responses = micropost.responses.size
     count = count + responses
    end
   count
end
```

But there's got to be a better Rails way (this smells of PHP)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the components are working independently, it might be as simple as adding a line to the end of your method: `responses`. After the `.each` loop executes, it returns the original array (not the value you modified within the loop). Since you want to return the number stored in `responses`, you want that variable to be the last line of your method.

Comment: No luck, not sure that should make a difference as the variable is declared but could be wrong (and probably am!)

Comment: You said a user has many microposts and has many responses - does that mean a user has many responses, or a user has many microposts and a micropost has many responses? Your code looks like it's assuming the latter, but if it's the former that complicates matters (you'd want to construct a relationship between microposts and responses so you could check if the micropost a response belongs to has a particular tag).

Comment: User has many microposts and has many responses. Micropost belongs to a user and has many responses. Response belongs to a user and belongs to a micropost.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the count in a single query like this:

```rb
microposts.tagged_with(tag, on: :tags).joins(:responses).where(responses: {user_id: id}).count
```